# Obtain the indices for alignment when considering insertioins

Tags: python

I have two amino acid sequences

reference sequence:
`SCAASGGSEYGTLVTVSSRGRHHHHHH`

target sequence:
`SCAASVRGTQVTVSSGPGGQHHHHHH`

Their alignment is this with insertion `-`

```
SCAASGGSEYGTLVTVSSR--GRHHHHHH
SCAAS---VRGTQVTVSSGPGGQHHHHHH
```

I want to know the corresponding indices in the target sequence by providing the reference indices. If the corresponding amino acid in the target is insertion `-`, just ignore it.

For example, indices `[0, 5, 20]` in the reference sequence (before alignment) corresponds to `['S', 'G', 'R']`. Its corresponding amino acid in the target sequence is `['S', '-', 'Q']` based on the alignment, which corresponds to `[0, 'N/A', 19]` in the target sequence (before alignment). How can I write a python code to output `[0, 19]` based on input `[0, 5, 20]` and the alignment?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: Have you looked into using [Biopython](https://biopython.org)?